# Unable to upload large files with filezilla

Tags: ubuntu, ftp, filezilla

I have two relatively large files 220 M and 440 M and I am unable to upload these files to a remote location in another country via FTP. When I try to resume the process after a failed upload it refuses and wants me to overwrite and start from beginning. Otherwise it automatically disconnects after a certain time and starts uploading from beginning in a vicious cycle. I am open to all suggestions.

Assuming my ISP has some restrictions on uploading(which I doubt as I downloaded a 1 GB file last year) what could be things I could look for  ? 
It could be that there is a problem with the server and if that is the case how can I let them know ?

Some of the logs that I found in Filezilla while the upload failed

```
19:50:10    Command:    PASV
19:50:10    Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (141,38,3,174,247,128).
19:50:10    Command:    REST 19796000
19:50:10    Response:   501 REST not compatible with server configuration
19:50:10    Error:  File transfer failed
19:50:10    Status: Starting upload of a.tar.gz
19:50:31    Status: Retrieving directory listing of "/upload"...
19:50:33    Status: Directory listing of "/upload" successful
20:00:33    Response:   421 Idle Timeout (600 seconds): closing control connection.
20:00:33    Error:  Connection closed by server
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The explanation is on line 4.

`501 REST not compatible with server configuration`

The server doesn't support [resuming uploads](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3659#section-5)..
There is not much you can do about it, unless you can contact the server admin and have him add that support (by changing FTP server software).

Comment: thank you so much ! At least I can let them know and leave it to them to decide what to do.

Comment: these are compressed files. You think I can split this up into smaller files and FTP ?

Comment: Yes, that would most likely work..

Comment: Also, please note that the `Response:   421 Idle Timeout (600 seconds): closing control connection.` message is just closing the control connection, not the data connection. Is the file being uploaded at all?